# Make this div responsive

Tags: html, css

I have tried width 100% but it didn't make it responsive. Here is link of what I'm trying to make responsive. It is not responsive. Help [codepen link](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KaEywJ)

```css
div {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EinaJ.png) top center;
  width:620px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:40px 40px 30px;
  height:590px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  justify-content:center;
}
img, p, footer {  
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
  background:pink
}
img {
  margin:auto auto 0;
}
footer {
  bottom:30px;
  right:45px;
  margin:auto 0 0;  
  border-radius:0 0 0.25em 0.25em ;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src=""> 
  <p>here is</p>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how responsive design works ? Have you tried using `%` instead of `px`, media queries ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KaEywJ   this is the link

Comment: yes I tried width:100% but it doesn't work ..... image or text is overflowing on resizing window @AymDev

Comment: thta's not just about setting `width: 100%` to a random div, it's about screen sizes and relative units. [Read some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive/Responsive) maybe ?

Comment: If the image is overflowing ave you told the img to contain is container. That is img {width: 100%;}

Comment: The fixed pixel width means that the div will never resize. Try setting the div to width:auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
:root {
  /*the percentage of screen width occupied by a block. 1 = 100% */
  --percent: .9;
}

div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EinaJ.png) top center;
    background-size: cover;
    /* for old browsers */
    width: 90vw;
    height: 113.61516034vw;
    /* for new browsers */
    width: calc(100vw*var(--percent));
    height: calc((100vw*var(--percent))*866/686);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 40px 40px 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

img,
p,
footer {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  /* see me */
  background: pink
}

img {
  margin: auto auto 0;
}

footer {
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 45px;
  margin: auto 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.25em 0.25em;
  /* see me */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

body {
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150" />
  <p>here is</p>
  <p>some line</p>
  <p>of</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: @koku19 Be aware that CSS variables used in this solution have bad browser support

Comment: @LGSon added for my solution the old browsers support.

Comment: Good, still, I don't see the point using a variable since you have to hard code the image size anyway, `866/686` ... I mean if it were dynamically read I could see the point, now it just make the CSS messy to read

Comment: @LGSon You are not right. The variable is needed because in using it you can set the block size relative to the browser window. And 686/866 it's just the size of the background, which was originally chosen by the author. Result of the division is required to maintain the correct aspect ratio. Tough nothing can be defined because it is rubber template.

Comment: Well, since in this case the result of the equation `100vw*var(--percent)` will always be `90vw`, why mess it up with a variable you have to go and check as soon as you read through the code? ... Also, its name does not give one any lead what so ever of what it does, so image having a hugh CSS and one need to move focus back and fourth ... but this is of course only my way of looking at it

Comment: @LGSon the size of the block required the author initially unknown. so I gave the ability to change virtually in one place, so you don't have to go deep with the jungle of css

Comment: How does that paper layer effect work? What is the general idea? Thank you!

Comment: @BigMonkey89WithaLeg This is just the calculation of block size relative to the size of the viewport. And the background stretched to full size of the block.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not responsive is because you have set the div's width and height to a specific pixel. Therefore it is not able to adjust.

**Try changing the pixel to a percentage:**

**For example:**

```
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: that's not working because it's making that white background image look cropped

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do.You're trying to have the div in the middle center and responsive.Set `margin:0 auto;` and `width:50%;`.Get rid of other bits of codes in the div.To make it responsive to mobile screen do:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:set_your_max){
    div { width:50%; }
}
```